# Getting select statement results from a stored procedure using JPA?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures

Using JPA, I'm calling a MS SQL Server 2008 R2 stored procedure that looks like this

```
procedure [dbo].[testProc]
    @param1 varchar(max),
    @param2 datetime
as
begin
EXEC sessionProc

DECLARE @reportData varbinary(max)

EXEC aThirdPartyProc
     @reportData out,
     @parameter1 = @param1,
     @date = @param2

SELECT col1, col2
FROM fFunction(@reportData)

end
```

When trying to get the results from the select statement

```
StoredProcedureQuery q = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("reportData");
q.setParameter("param1", "val1");
q.setParameter("param2", new Date());
return (List<ReportData>) q.getResultList();
```

I get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current CallableStatement ou was not a ResultSet, but getResultList was called
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.getResultList(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:319)
```

**How can I get the select statement results?**

Note: The JPA code works if I reduce testProc to a simple select (remove the two EXEC statements).

Also, here's the ReportData entity class:

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "reportData", procedureName = "testProc", resultClasses = ReportData.class, parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "param1", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "param2", type = Date.class)
          })
public class ReportData {
    @Id
    private String col1;
    private String col2;
    // getter and setter for col1 and col2
}
```

I've tested the proc in SQL Server Management Studio and it works fine returning results from the select statement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Feedback from multiple queries within SPs throw JPA off unless `SET NOCOUNT ON;` is used.

Insert `SET NOCOUNT ON;` after BEGIN in your SP.

Using `SET NOCOUNT ON` is a [general best practice](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1226/set-nocount-on-improves-sql-server-stored-procedure-performance/).

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a parameter with `mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR` and let your stored procedure return refcursor.

and then use

```
q.execute();
return (List<ReportData>) q.getResultList();
```

See [here](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/call-stored-procedures-jpa/) section **Stored procedures with REF_CURSOR**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, SQL Server JDBC does not support ref cursors. Please see [Micrsoft's JDBC 4.2 Compliance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt221491(v=sql.110).aspx). The "Noteworthy Implementation" column describing the `supportsRefCursors` method of `SQLServerDatabaseMetaData` contains the relevant information. I've also attempted it (with jTDS and Microsoft's driver) and I get `Dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect] not known to support REF_CURSOR parameters`

Comment: Hi @James, have you solved the problem with SQL Server drivers?

Comment: @Rodolfo Martins - No. I worked around the issue by breaking the original stored proc into multiple stored procs. Then, on the Java side, I call each stored procs. (In my case, I needed the calls executed in a single transaction). Dkroot's answer may also work. I need to set some time aside to test.