# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current CallableStatement ou was not a ResultSet, but getResultList was called

Tags: hibernate, stored-procedures, hibernate-entitymanager

I am trying to call stored procedure below way, but I am getting exception- Current CallableStatement ou was not a ResultSet, but getResultList was called

```
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    StoredProcedureQuery proc = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("SPCL_LIST_BEN_UNI_ID");              
    
    proc.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_adt_usr_id", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    proc.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_lng", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    proc.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_act_id", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);

    proc.setParameter("p_adt_usr_id", "HALLAGE1");
    proc.setParameter("p_lng", "ENG");
    proc.setParameter("p_act_id", "1AN76VZ");
    proc.execute();
    proc.getResultList();
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current CallableStatement ou was not a ResultSet, but getResultList was called
at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getResultList(ProcedureCallImpl.java:721)
at ca.bnc.wealth.batch.service.lei.SequentialNumberService.getResult(SequentialNumberService.java:73)
at ca.bnc.wealth.batch.service.lei.SequentialNumberService.procedureCall(SequentialNumberService.java:51)
... 24 common frames omitted

Can Someone please help?

Comment: Your stored procedure doesn't return a result set, just like the exception says.

Comment: Stored procedure returns resultset. however it seems StoredProcedureQuery does not support resultset. I have tried with SimpleJdbcCall and I am able to retrieve resultset successfully

Answer (score 0):

As [Dima-Korobskiy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/534217/dima-korobskiy) mentioned in his [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43418821),
The issue is often related to multiple queries within stored procedures confusing JPA, and a recommended solution has been provided.

Insert the following code after the `BEGIN` statement in your stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Stored procedure content goes here

END
```

Place `SET NOCOUNT ON;` immediately before the `BEGIN` block in your stored procedure named `"SPCL_LIST_BEN_UNI_ID"`. This ensures that when a result set is created within the stored procedure, JPA will handle it correctly.

The final code should look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPCL_LIST_BEN_UNI_ID
    @p_adt_usr_id NVARCHAR(255),
    @p_lng NVARCHAR(255),
    @p_act_id NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Stored procedure content goes here

END
```